# Create model in model

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm new to strongloop and look at documentation and samples but never see my problem as desired. 
I'v two models, sentence.js and log.js and making post request a sentence from mobile app to rest-api, for example

```
Model sentence.js (dont want save to db this model, only for parsing and creating log model)
{
  name: 'sentence',
  type: 'string'
}

Model  log.js
{ name: 'lat', type: 'string' },
{ name: 'lng', type: 'string' }

[HTTP POST]  myserver/api/sentence?d=$GPRMC,123519,A,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,022.4,084.4,230394,003.1,W*6A
```

A model has triggered methods, e.g, afterInitialize, beforeValidate , beforeSave. Now, **which triggered method or any other scope correct and best for parsing sentence model and creating log model ?**

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the best place is

```
Sentence.beforeRemote('create', function(ctx, sentence, next){
  console.log(ctx.req.body); 
  next()
})
```

Also [Model hook](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+hooks) `Sentence.afterInitialize` and [Model Event](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+class#model) `Sentence.on('set')` are available, but will be called in some extra cases.

(Note that in my case I would use remote hooks and only ONE Log model.)

Comment: Thanks, so what about creating and saving log.js model in this scope ?

Comment: Yes you can do it, accessing Log model through 
`Sentence.app.models.Log` or
`require('../../server/server.js').models.Log` or `require('loopback').getModel('Log')`.


In my project I place hooks in separate files and plug in them in server/boot/root.js, using `require('../hooks/sentence.js')(server)`. So inside sentence.js I have a reference to models like so: `server.models.Log`.