# strongloop creating related model object in afterRemote method

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

say i have a game scenario.

a game belongs to a user.

game.json:

```
{
  "name": "game",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "beer_points_required": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "total_points": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "game_blngs_to_user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

user.json:

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "last_game": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": false
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": []
}
```

I'm attempting to create a game object for a user programmatically after the user has been created through CRUD, so inside the user.js i have:

```
var config = require('../../server/config.json');
var path = require('path');
var app = require('../app');

module.exports = function(user) {

user.afterRemote('create', function(context, user) {
    console.log('> user.afterRemote triggered');

  //create a game for each user thats created
  var Game = app.models.game;
  game.create({game_blngs_to_userId: user.id, beer_points_required: 0, total_points: 0},function(err, res){
 if(err){
      console.log('\n\n>>err');
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(res);
  });
});
```

However, this obviously didn't work lol so I'm wondering how to actually accomplish my goal. I've been staring at strong loops docs for a long time and it seems like actual usage of their api is not that well documented...well at least in my eyes. could anyone please shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Can you clarify, what is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, you're missing 3rd parameter -  `next` function in afterRemote callback.

```
user.afterRemote('create', function(context, user, next) {
  ...
  var Game = app.models.game;
  game.create({game_blngs_to_userId: user.id, beer_points_required: 0, total_points: 0},function(err, res){
 if(err){
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    next() // countinue execution
  });
});
```

Comment: im testing this out at the moment, i'll let you know soon. thank you!!

Comment: i believe your answer will work, however, i couldn't keep the line `var app = require('../app');` it wouldn't compile it (if compile is the right word) so the server wouldn't start. therefore i believe that the instance of app of the line `var Game = app.models.game;` is undefined. how can i get a valid instance of app? or at least, a valid instance of game.

Comment: Check this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599031/create-model-in-model/27602409#comment43631772_27602409

Answer (score 0):

i think your user reference is undefined...try:

`app.models.user.afterRemote`

Comment: user works, the problem is that i cannot create game and set the blngs_to to the user. i doesn't even go in the game.create function. any thoughts?

Comment: use `var Game = user.app.models.game;`